# how to get only the second index of a data frame with a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

first of all, I am pretty new to python so please go easy on me.
I need to get a certain value from a data frame.

I got this code:

data frame for the first input:

```
symbol   date          bmo amc             company name

AAP    2019-05-22  Before The Open         Advance Auto
ADI    2019-05-22  Before The Open       Analog Devices
CM     2019-05-22  Before The Open                 CIBC
CSWI   2019-05-22  Before The Open      CSW Industrials
KLXE   2019-05-22  Before The Open  KLX Energy Services
```

```
for stock_symbol in mystocks:
    print(stock_symbol)
```

input:

```
#get the date from the date column
ddate = df_earning_calander.loc[
    df_earning_calander.index == stock_symbol, 'date'][stock_symbol]
print(ddate)
```

output:

```
AAP
2019-05-22 00:00:00
```

data frame for the second input:

```
symbol         Stock name         date               ...
AAP     Advance Auto Parts Inc 2018-11-13            ...
AAP     Advance Auto Parts Inc 2019-02-15            ...
AAP     Advance Auto Parts Inc 2019-02-19            ...
AAP     Advance Auto Parts Inc 2019-05-21            ...
AAP     Advance Auto Parts Inc 2019-05-22            ...
```

input:

```
#get all the dates from the date column
ddate_12 = df_earnings_12.loc[
    df_earnings_12.index == stock_symbol, 'date'][stock_symbol]
print(ddate_12)
```

output:

```
AAP   2018-11-13
AAP   2019-02-15
AAP   2019-02-19
AAP   2019-05-21
AAP   2019-05-22
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
if ddate in ddate_12:
    continue
```

well, I am trying to check if the date from the first data frame is in the second data frame and (while the stock name is the same).
this code does not go to the next iterable. I think it is because the second output gives me the stock name and date and not only the date.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: In markdown if you want to skip a line use 2 spaces and enter instead of `<br>`

Comment: @jezrael thanks I add the data frame so people can see what this is about.

Comment: @Craicerjack I tried to do 2 spaces but it won't work...

Comment: no, I need to check if the date from the first data frame exists in the second data frame (for the same stock). i think the problem is in the second print, it prints both stock name and date. i want it to print only the date i think this is the solution i am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only date column, create 2 columns `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and if possible duplicated pairs add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df_earning_calander['date'].reset_index().drop_duplicates()
print (df1)
  symbol        date
0    AAP  2019-05-22
1    ADI  2019-05-22
2     CM  2019-05-22
3   CSWI  2019-05-22
4   KLXE  2019-05-22

df2 = df_earnings_12['date'].reset_index().drop_duplicates()
print (df2)
  symbol        date
0    AAP  2018-11-13
1    AAP  2019-02-15
2    AAP  2019-02-19
3    AAP  2019-05-21
4    AAP  2019-05-22
```

Then for intersection between both DatFrames with same columns names use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join - get all symbols matching with all datetimes between both:

```
df = df1.merge(df2)
print (df)
  symbol        date
0    AAP  2019-05-22
```

Last if need test list of symbols compare column `df['symbol']` for boolean mask and test if at least one `True` by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
mystocks = ['ADI','AAP']
for stock_symbol in mystocks:
    if ((df['symbol'] == stock_symbol).any()):
        print (f'Matched {stock_symbol}')
        #Matched AAP
```